# Where can I find the failover history for an Azure SQL Database with geo replication?

Tags: replication, azure-sql-database

We have an Azure SQL Database that is geo replicated to another region. I suspect that they have swapped which is primary and which is secondary and would like to find information about when that has occurred. Where would I find that history?

Comment: Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-geo-replication-link-status-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current

Comment: That shows the status of the link, but no information about failovers.